# Ability to lock dask worker till certain post task / steps are complete

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

Trying to submit task to worker and return results. However need to perform garbage collection on worker to avoid memory build up from existing task. Would like to perform gc async and return the value from worker but avoid the worker from picking new tasks till the gc is complete.

Looked into distributed.Lock a bit but not sure if that can help here. Also wondering if secede() would help here.

Answer (score 0):

Python processes call `gc.collect` regularly.  It is usually not necessary to call it manually.

If you want, you can call `client.run(gc.collect)` to run this function on all Dask workers.